# R Raster .tif File: selecting raster@data@attributes

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm using R's raster package to access the USDA National Crop Data Layer.
This is a .tif file. Within the Raster Object are a number of @data@attributes
that sit in a data frame. These are like bands, but they are not bands.

Here's the Crop Data Layer for Colorado:

```
CDL <- raster("cdl_30m_r_co_2015_albers.tif")
```

And here's a snippet of the attributes I want to select from:

```
> CDL@data@attributes

[[1]]
      ID   COUNT                 Class.Names Opacity
1     0        0                  Background       0
2     1  5133840                        Corn     255
3     2        0                      Cotton     255
4     3        0                        Rice     255
```

I'd like to be able to select some of these attributes in a new raster to plot or do calculations on them. (I think the COUNT is counts of pixels in the raster.) There are 256 attributes.

How might I do this?

So I have the answer, duh.

It is as simple as just doing a comparison on the raster for the value I want.

```
Corn <- CDL == 1
```

(A tif file in the raster sense, I think, is just a normal tif image with georeferencing. It is just a x rows by y cols bitmap and in this case the values
for each pixel are the values in the raster@data@attributes data frame ID column.)

Helps to know that the file format contains the answer the question.

Thanks

Comment: use `levels` to see the attributes, and see functions like `deratify` for other options